# ag-Grid : enter edit mode programmatically

Tags: ag-grid

I have a grid with `singleClickEdit` set true.

I want to enter in edit mode when the grid finishes loading or when the user finishes editing a row.
I have tried with API `setFocusedCell(rowIndex, colKey, floating)` but it just focus the cell without enter editing.
The goal is to build speed editing grid and never use the mouse...

Is there a way to do that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: May I ask how you get the colKey for focusing? I'm trying to achieve the same as you did but ag-grid is throwing stones in my way left and right

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get a reference to the `grid` by using `gridReady/onGridReady` callback and then call [startEditingCell](https://ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/) function on `grid.api`.

> `grid.api.startEditingCell(params)`: Starts editing the provided cell. If another
>   cell is editing, the editing will be stopped in that other cell.
>
> Parameters are as follows:
>   `rowIndex`: The row index of the row to start editing.
>   `colKey`: The column key of the column to start editing.
>   `keyPress, charPress`: The keyPress and charPress that are passed to the cellEditor

Comment: Any idea how I'd specify a pinned row? When trying a `rowIndex` of 0 it will select the first unpinned row

Comment: @aus_10 - the params also takes a rowPinned parameter - set it to "top" or "bottom"